# Going from CORBA WLE in C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, corba, tuxedo

We are trying to ditch our WLE/Tuxedo/BEA/etc legacy licenses, and get Java instead. We have some old CORBA clients who are out of development, so we must be backward-compatible. if they are trying to connect using the TObj_Boostrap and/or the FactoryFinder, is there any way I can get around this? I'm willing to write anything on the server side, if absolutely necessary to a roll-your-own.

Comment: Rolling my own. With the help of wireshark, I was able to see what, exactly, was being sent via WLE and customized some JacORB objects to fool them. Since the WLE requests come in unique, I can have it return a WLE-esque response for only those requests. For exapmle, a FactoryFinder is really just a NameServer, but only for 'factory' objects. No reason I can't have NameServer return those on a WLE request. Inelegant, to be sure, but I couldn't find any better option.